# jQuery can't get display value of a span, when using a class only style

Tags: jquery

below are two different methods of setting the display to none for a span container, one using a class and another using style.

html code

```
<div>

<style>
.KPfc{display:none}
</style>

<span style="display:none">ABC</span>
<span class="KPfc">DEF</span>

</div>
```

i want to then check all the span containers, and check which ones are set to "none" however the following only seems to be able to access css within a style, not a class.

```
$data.find("div span").each(function() {
    temp = $(this).css('display')
    console.log("status = " + temp);
});
```

additional code edit:

```
<span>

<style>
.CfV9{display:none}
.BPcy{display:inline}
.oWnI{display:none}
.ryU9{display:inline}
.WxoV{display:none}
.Z_bV{display:inline}
.KPfc{display:none}
</style>

<span></span>
120
<span style="display:none"></span>
<span class="CfV9">190</span>
<span></span>
<span style="display:none"></span><
span class="oWnI">222</span>
<span style="display: inline">.</span>
<div style="display:none">86</div>
<span class="KPfc">180</span>
<span></span>
<span class="174">203</span>
<span class="17">.</span>
<span class="BPcy">214</span>
.
<span style="display:none"></span>
<span class="oWnI">17</span>
<span></span>
<div style="display:none">139</div>
<span style="display:none"></span>
<div style="display:none">140</div>
<span class="CfV9">147</span>
<span></span>
<span class="128">172</span>

</span>
```

Comment: your `$("#div")` selector should be `$("div")`

Comment: I got both `span` return `none` from you code, can you put up a jsfiddle?

Comment: i have included in the original post the raw code i am trying to perform this on, and can't get it to work, my example was  a cut down version.

Comment: i guess you need to fingure out your selctor, `div span` obviously doesn't match your raw HTML provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$('div span').not(':visible')...
```

As the selector. The `:visible` should get if they are visible or not.

(by the way, the above code is selecting invisible divs and spans. To get only the visible ones it would be `$('div span:visible')`)